# Why do you say "TCP port"?

Tags: port, tcp

I'm learning networking and sockets and there's something I don't understand. I often heard about "TCP ports"
But I think ports are related to the application layer (80 for HTTP servers for example).
So why don't you say "applications ports" ? Why port seems associated with TCP layer (it should be associated with an higher layer) ?
For me ports have nothing to do with TCP protocol

Thanks

Comment: Based on @mihai answer combined with mine: 
Combining the port number and the TCP/UDP you "create" the name of the assigned protocol, not vice-versa.

Eq:

     TCP:80 = HTTP
     TCP:23 = Telnet
     UDP:220 = IMAP

You don't say HTTP:80 is TCP. The TCP port 80 is known as HTTP.

You have your official answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding is incorrect, and you need to clarify this point before moving on to other networking concepts.

*Port* is a fundamental concept of TCP.

TCP is a bidirectional communication protocol between two endpoints (`Source` and `Destination`), which are identified by 2 things: `IP address` and `Port`. TCP is meant to extend the IP protocol (which identifies hosts only by `IP address`) by adding the `Port` and allowing multiple communication endpoints to exist for a single IP address.

In fact TCP packets (sent over the wire) encapsulate IP packets, but add some  extra information on top of IP, information like the `Port` and some transmission control flags. This is why people often use the term TCP/IP.

On top of TCP/IP, people have built other protocols, like HTTP.

An HTTP packet (or request) consists of multiple TCP/IP packets exchanged between the client and the server. HTTP **uses** TCP/IP, and all packets sent with HTTP are TCP/IP packets. HTTP *commonly* uses the TCP port 80, however it can run on any other port without issues.

Also, any other application level protocol can be configured to use port 80.

Ports are associated with application level protocols only by convention. Similarly, SSH is *commonly* configured on port 22, but can be used on any other port.

Comment: As a side note, HTTP/3 uses UDP/IP. Not to make things more complicated, he! he! Things in IT are become more and more complex as time passes.

Comment: This is one of the best most concise explanations I've ever read on this topic. Chapeau :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a official definition of you people say it like this :)
This is only my idea, maybe it will help you :)

Because applications are using 2 protocols:
**TCP** and **UDP** and people to express both the using protocol of an application and the port, they say TCP:80 or UDP:5000 (torrent example)

For example HTTPS can run over any reliable stream transport protocol. Normally that's TCP, but it could also be SCTP. It is NOT expected to run over UDP.
So you can say HTTPS:443 or TCP:443 referring at the HTTPS discussion of course.
They guy that you are talking to, understands from the start that HTTPS uses TCP protocol and it is on 443 port.

Combining the port number and the TCP/UDP you "create" the name of the assigned protocol, not vice-versa.

Eq:

```
TCP:80 = HTTP
TCP:23 = Telnet
UDP:220 = IMAP
```

You don't say HTTP:80 is TCP. The TCP port 80 is known as HTTP.

For a list or protocols and ports see: http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1868080